# PHP regex for RE PHP 1000

Tags: php, regex

I want to do the scenario below:

```
RE PHP 100 = True
RE PHP 10001 asdadads = True
RE PHP 100sdsd01 asdadads = False
XRE PHP 1001 = FALSE
RE xPHP 1001 = FALSE
(RE) (PHP) (INTEGER) (EOF OR Some string)
```

I'm trying to use this regex:

```
if(preg_match("/^RE[ ]PHP[ ]([\d])?$/", "RE PHP 1",$matches))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the square brackets around the spaces or `\d`. You do need a `+` after the `\d`.

```
/^RE PHP \d+( \w+)?$/
```